# NoSuchMethodException with a Radio Button

Tags: android

I'm attempting to write a form, and at one point there are 2 radio buttons asking for the gender of the person. I want to require that at least one button is pressed, or they receive a toast. They appear in the activity_main as such:

```
<RadioGroup 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/female" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/male" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And the relevant code in the MainActivity:

```
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    if(!rb1.isChecked() && !rb2.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a gender.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

It may be worth noting that I've tried doing the if statement with only one &, and my app still crashes upon clicking a radio button.

Here is the LogCat:

```
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.myapplication.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'radioButton1'
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRadioButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
09-11 01:21:26.599: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  ... 12 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method `onRadioButtonClicked` because you have set `onClick` in `xml`. So you must have a method with that name in `Activity` which can handle the click.

Method

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){
    // Your code on click
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
  private RadioButton radioSexButton;
  private Button btnDisplay;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        if(selected==-1)
                             Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                "Please Select at least one Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you define

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v)
```

as your line

```
android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
```

implies?

Answer (score 0):

Define properties onClick in xml file onRadioButtonClicked and access for this method on java file,

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.YOUR_ID_RADIO_BUTTON:
                    // write here some one code
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```